# Any mysql select to "skip" results?

Tags: mysql, select

I´m trying to do a "select" that groups and displays the results from the column "campus" but skip or don´t show the other remaining rows from the other columns like "dependencia", "cuenta".
Any ideas?
PS I´m a newbie in mysql.
[SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9MDK.jpg)

Comment: Use the `WHERE` clause to filter rows you don't want

Comment: A select query returns rows. These rows contain columns. What does "displays the results from the column "campus"" mean? What does "the other remaining rows from the other columns" mean? Use the correct terminology and/or show a concrete example. And post any code you want to post as text, in the question. Not as a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select campus from tablename
```

This will only show the campus column.

Add a where clause to filter results:

```
Select campus from tablename
Where campus='xyz'
```